# CustomView style not applied to programmatically added TextView in android

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-custom-view

I have a custom view for creating a button and applied a style for it. I am adding label to the button by creating TextView programmatically in the custom View class.

Below is the style which I applied to the custom View

```
    <style name="VRButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/vr_button_height</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/vr_button_start_end_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/vr_button_start_end_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/vr_button_top_bottom_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/vr_button_top_bottom_padding</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/vr_content_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/vr_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/VRTextContentStyle</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
</style>
<style name="VRTextContentStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|start</item>
    <item name="android:fontStyle">normal</item>
    **<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/vr_font_family_text</item>**
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/vr_text_font_size</item>
    <item name="android:spacing">@dimen/vr_text_line_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">@dimen/vr_text_letter_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/vr_color3</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/vr_transparent_color</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

In the above code, fontFamily is applied to the style "VRTextContentStyle" which then added as "textAppearance" to the first style. My issue is , when I use font like this, it is not reflecting in the text which I add programatically in my custom class. But it is working when I add the "android:fontStyle" to the parent style directly.

Below is my custom view xml.

```
                 <com.vr.myapp.button.VRButton
                    android:id="@+id/confirm_button"
                    style="@style/VRButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/vr_content_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/vr_text_font_size"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>
```

In the current implementation, font is not getting applied to my text view , but When I use "@font/vr_font_family_text" in my parent style (i.e @style/VRButtonStyle) it is found properly applied.
Any suggestions are appreciated.